# How to implement PrimeFaces example into JSF page?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I want to implement Prime Faces [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf)

I created this JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_application.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <p:spinner /> 
                    <h:form id="form">
                        <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true">

                            <p:tab id="tba1" title="Godfather Part I">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.
                                        His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T
                                        hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,
                                        but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>

                            <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                                    <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.
                                                  In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,
                                                  killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>

                            <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                                    <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.
                                                  Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>

                        </p:tabView>
                    </h:form>


                </div>   


                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">


                </div>   



            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

I don't know why but I can see only plain text - there are no tabs? What am I missing?

Best wishes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen if you haven't actually installed PrimeFaces in your webapp.

[Download](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html) the JAR file, drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and rebuild/redeploy/restart.

Comment: Yes, I also added PrimeFaces as dependency according these instructions: http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html but the result is the same. I get this message: Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no tag library exists for that namespace

Comment: You must have done something wrong. This warning indicates that it's still not in webapp's runtime classpath. As said, download the JAR and drop it in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp. Nothing else needs to be done.